# redirect .html file to .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect each and every page (from sub directories too) to be redirect to .php file.

like abc.html to abc.php and if abc.php does not exists it should show 404

Here is my htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1.html [QSA]
```

It redirects only some of the pages to php and it also redirects to some php file which is not exists there inside the folder.

How to solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: it does the same , displays a url with .php extension in address bar and opens with content of html file , but not actually displaying .php file content.

Comment: If you want it to be done as a redirect instead of just a rewrite modify the [L] to [L,R]

Answer (score 8):

You can try either of the two approaches.

Approach 1: Use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R]
```

Approach 2: Add the following to HTML file

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
CONTENT="0; URL="http://www.yoursite.com/redirect_location">
```

Here you have the option to delay the redirect by increasing the CONTENT variable. For example, CONTENT=5 will delay the redirect for 5 seconds.